# Тонкости приведения типов в условии цикла for

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
string s, tmp;
cin >> s;
for(int i = 0; i < s.size() - 4; ++i)
{
    tmp = s.substr(i, 5);
    // на этом месте вылетает, если строка меньше 4 символов
    // ругается на то, что __pos больше длины строки
}
```

Почему `s.size() - 4` **положительное** число при `s.size() < 4`?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно в документацию по std::string. Какой тип возвращает метод size()? Какое значение будет у size_t=3, если из него вычесть 4?

Comment: А причём здесь цикл `for`?

Comment: @VladD при том, что методы size() часто используются именно в нём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что значение, возвращаемое `s.size()`, имеет тип `unsigned` (беззнаковое), поэтому `s.size() - 4` всегда больше `0`.

Например, если длина равна 3, тогда 3 - 4 = -1, что соответствует `0xFFFFFFFF`, равное `MAX_INT`, т. е. примерно `2*10^9`).

В данном случаи поможет  `(int)s.size()-4`

Comment: Всё это может иметь место для x86, для amd64 цифры будут совсем другие. Кроме того, если уже приводите `size()` к signed type, то лучше использовать `size_t` "брата" - `ptrdiff_t`, который гарантировано имеет одинаковый размер с `size_t`, а не `int`

Comment: Ну и `0xFFFFFFFF` для `int` это `-1`, а не `MAX_INT`, вероятно Вы имели ввиду `UINT_MAX`